# ReactJS Moment is not formatting date correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have a function for displaying the first date of the week and it's result are displayed as followed:

Mon Nov 12 2018 08:14:09 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)

...what am attempting to do is display the result with the month only:
2018-11-12

...here is the function for getting the first day of the week:

```
let sd = new Date();
const startOfWeek = (date) => {
  let diff = date.getDate() - date.getDay() + (date.getDay() === 0 ? -6 : 1);
  return new Date(date.setDate(diff));
}
```

...I call the function as followed:

```
const startDay = startOfWeek(sd).toString();
```

...Here is where I Use moment to apply the formatting:

```
moment(startDay).format('YYYY MMMM Do');
```

...but my date still displays the following:
Mon Nov 12 2018 08:14:09 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)

...could I get some help as to what am doing wrong?

Comment: The `.format()` function *returns* the formatted string. It does not forever establish the formatting for the object.

Comment: FYI, Moment has a [`startOf`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) function...

Comment: You might also want to look at [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/), as it uses immutable objects, which might be a better fit for React.

Comment: Can you add more code where you use the line `moment(startDay).format('YYYY MMMM Do');` please? It's not clear why you are getting the output "Mon Nov 12 2018 08:14:09 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)" having looked at your moment format string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, the format was incorrect though, it should be `YYYY-MM-D`

```
let sd = new Date();
const startOfWeek = (date) => {
  let diff = date.getDate() - date.getDay() + (date.getDay() === 0 ? -6 : 1);
  return new Date(date.setDate(diff));
}
const startDay = startOfWeek(sd)
console.log(moment(startDay).format('YYYY-MM-D'));
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked, and even when outputted in the console, the format is what I wanted; ...but, via the browser it still shows Mon Nov 12 2018 10:54:17 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) ...still your remedy works when outputted via the console. Any ideal why it want reflect in the webpage? Am using Reactjs

Comment: How are you displaying it ? can you share your snippet?

Answer (score 1):

I think the moment js format you are looking for is:

`moment(startDay).format('YYYY-MM-DD');`

The format `YYYY MMMM Do` would return a string like: "2018 November 13th".

Comment: strange, this works when outputted to the console, but the browser still shows the following: Mon Nov 12 2018 11:08:23 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) ... an showing the date in a text input field, though I do think that show make a difference.